# Styles from a separate .css file not applying to component in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to recreate app-part-slot component from a React project in Angular, but none of the styles from the css file are being applied to the component. The styles appear inside the `<head>` tag though, but the browser doesn't seem to notice them. It seems that browser has no problem getting the styles file contents.

I've created this component with a CLI command and got the following file structure:

```
part-slot
| part-slot.component.css
| part-slot.component.ts
...
```

Path to the styles file was automatically included in the Component decorator, I've double-checked this path is valid, the IDE manages to point to the correct file when I press "Go to definition". That's how the decorator looks:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-part-slot',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './part-slot.component.html',
  styleUrl: './part-slot.component.css'
})
```

I've tried replacing styleurl with styleurls in decorator with no effect. I've also tried importing the file into styles.css, I'm not really sure if it's something I needed to do in my situation, but it didn't help anyway. The CSS itself seems correct, at least it worked fine with React.

Is there something I can do about this problem? Thanks in advance.

I'll post my project files contents if there's such a need. Angular version is 17.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use styleUrls, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-part-slot',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './part-slot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./part-slot.component.css']
})
```

You were missing also a ' for closing the path of the css file in your piece of code.

If you're using VScode, check for any extensions which asks for a required reload, that might create false-positive sometime.

Also try to restart angular compiler as sometime one of these 3 variables, can get stuck and your environment is not clean.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the playground you provided, the problem is not the css, it's the className attribute set on HTML elements. Angular works with plain class. So for instance:

React code:

```
<div className="CssAmazingClass">text</div>
```

Angular equivalent code:

```
<div class="CssAmazingClass">text</div>
```

Also you have different ways of setting css classes, I suggest to have a look at [this link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) which explain also ngClass directive, and gives you an insight about more advanced and dynamic use-cases.

Anyway in your case, changing from:

```
<div className="PartSlot">

  <div className='IconMountLower'> 
    <div className='IconMountUpper'>
        <img [src]="iconAddress" className="Icon" alt="Part icon"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="PartInfoHolder">
    <div className="Text PartName">{{ partClassName }}</div>
    <div className="Text ModelName">{{ partName }}</div>
    <div className="Text PartPrice">{{ partPrice }}</div>
  </div>

  <div className="ArrowMount">
    <img src="assets/Chevron_right.svg" className="ArrowIcon" alt=""/>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

to this, fixes your problems:

```
<div class="PartSlot">

  <div class='IconMountLower'> 
    <div class='IconMountUpper'>
        <img [src]="iconAddress" className="Icon" alt="Part icon"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="PartInfoHolder">
    <div class="Text PartName">{{ partClassName }}</div>
    <div class="Text ModelName">{{ partName }}</div>
    <div class="Text PartPrice">{{ partPrice }}</div>
  </div>

  <div class="ArrowMount">
    <img src="assets/Chevron_right.svg" class="ArrowIcon" alt=""/>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

[Working playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fiah2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Using styleurls didn't help unfotunately. I've also disabled all vscode plugins. Did you mean restarting the terminal and running ng serve again by "restart angular compiler"?

Comment: yep, I meant that. Sometime when you disable extensions / plugins, or you change some property in the component / directive and it's a path to a file, there might be something that get stuck. closing the process in the terminal and running ng serve, does clean the compiler and run the project again. Also you should consider using npm run serve, instead of ng serve ( as it uses the actual compiler of the project itself instead of running your global one ). Did you check your syntax on the styleUrl definition? Can you update the your initial post with your actual code now or setup a playground?

Comment: I've set up a [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fiah2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpart-slot%2Fpart-slot.component.css)

Comment: ok, I update my answer, the problem is className and not class, the css is importing fine

Comment: I didn't even think to consider old React markup as a source of problems. Thanks a lot